How can I power 28VDC devices from a 24VDC system?
I need to power a couple of aircraft type appliances (coffee makers) from a diesel engine.  Aircraft standard voltage is 28VDC and each device needs 30 amps.  The engine has a 24-volt/160A alternator.  What would be the best way to get the extra 4 volts at 30 amps?  I looked at various DC/DC converters, but most of them either can't handle the current or can only step down the voltage.

Is the alternator not made to charge a lead-acid battery (24V rating, ~28V nominal charge)?

Have you tried the coffee makers at the lower voltage?  The might work well enough.

The heating element is just a resistor, so should work, just slightly lower temp.   Most electronics operate at much lower voltages, so any "smarts" in there should already be down converting to 5V or 3.3V for chips etc.

Your aircraft equipment (if it's civil) is almost certainly certified to DO-160, and it specifies the voltage range for 28V devices to be 22-30.3V standard. Surges/Transients are roughly similar to those specified for automotive applications.

Short story: Your aircraft gizmos will work at 24 volts.
We call 28-volt and 14-volt systems 24 and 12 volts to confuse communists and laymen. Aircraft and vehicles' battery operating voltages are 28 and 14 volts, respectively. 12 and 24 volts are the nominal battery voltages, which have little to do with operating voltages unless there is a power failure like the engine quits running or you lose commercial power to your battery plants.
For example, radio and telephone equipment operate on 24 and 48-volt battery plants. Under normal operating conditions, the batteries do not do anything. They float at 100% full charge, waiting for commercial power or the generators to fail. The batteries float on the rectifiers. The rectifiers supply all the power to the equipment. 24-volt plants float at 28, and 48-volt plants float at 52 volts. If the plant voltage ever drops to 24 or 48 volts, there will be a lot of alarms going off and many people panicking to restore power before the batteries discharge and drop service.
The same applies to aircraft and vehicle lead acid batteries. The alternator charges them up to 14 and 28 volts, and the battery floats while the alternator supplies power to all the electrical systems.
12, 24, and 48-volt battery equipment must operate over a wide range of operating voltages, from fully discharged to equalization charge voltage.  I will use a 12-volt system for minimum and maximum operating range. Double the figures for 24-volt systems and double again for 48 volts. The equipment must operate from a full discharge voltage of 1.75/vpc (10.5 volts) up to an EQ charge of 2.4/vpc (14.4 volts). Float voltage is roughly 13.8 to 14 volts depending on the exact Pb battery types, like flooded or AGM.
FWIW, there are two battery chemistries compatible with 12, 24, and 48-volt battery systems: naturally Lead-Acid and LFP cells. A 4SLFP pack is fully discharged at 10.5 volts, charged at 14.4 volts, and floats happily at 13.8 to 14 volts its whole life. That is why all lithium car batteries are LFP, a perfect match.

I'm confused by your joke in the first sentence. Where does communism come into it??

@Hearth, it means I am much older than you. Communist countries used to and are known to steal technology. It is a joke; instructors used to explain things that do not add up. Another one is we measure it with a micrometer, mark it with chalk, and cut it with an axe. Want to hear how resistor color code was taught and what Violet gave away?

@Dereck please, pretty please, tell us. As a proud citizen of once-communist country, I am curious about these jokes. And yes, we did have jokes about "doing something to confuse capitalists".

The reason aircraft use 28VDC is that 28VDC is the float voltage on a 24VDC lead-acid battery. They prefer 24VDC over 12VDC because less copper is required to transfer the same amount of power, so lighter. Each lead acid cell is about 2.1V so the aircraft will use 12 cells in series.
The system voltage in most cars when the alternator is spinning is about 14V, and your generator should produce double that, so I think you can just use it as is. Coffee makers are not that fussy anyway, a volt or two lower and it will just take a bit longer.
